# How to write more than 7 digits in effect ("slider control") because his stop in 6 number

Tags: animation

How to write more than 7 digits in effect ("slider control") because his stop in 6 number in after effects
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can right-click on the slider and select Edit Value. A dialogue box pops up. You can enter a number up to 1000000. If you need a bigger number, consider adding some text to the value using different units or extra zeroes.

[image]